# Doesn't work after writing it inside a class

Tags: javascript

I'm practicing some Javascript and I'm trying to figure out how to move a div from the left of the screen to the right. I did this in a separate file to test it first and it works, however, if I create a class and put my functions and variables inside it stops working and Firebug doesnt give me back any error. Can anyone help me?
Here's the code I figured out:

```
function crear_div (){
    this.pos_x      = 10;
    this.pos_y      = 10;
    this.x_min  = 10;
    this.x_max  = 500;
    this.y_min  = 10;
    this.y_max  = 500;

    this.incremento = 10;
    this.estado = 0;
    this.id_elemento = "pelota";

    this.f0 = f0;
    this.f2 = f2;

}

function f0(){
    this.pos_x   = this.pos_x + this.incremento;
    document.getElementById(this.id_elemento).style.left = this.pos_x + "px";
    if (this.pos_x >= this.x_max){
        this.estado = 1;
    }
}

function f2(){
    this.pos_x   = this.pos_x - this.incremento;
    document.getElementById(id_elemento).style.left = this.pos_x + "px";
    if (this.pos_x <= this.x_min){
        this.estado = 0;
    }
}

function desplazar(){
    switch(this.estado){
    case 0: 
        this.f0();
        break;
    case 1:
        this.f2();
        break;
    }
}

window.setInterval(function () {this.desplazar();}, 250);
```

Comment: `this` isn't set in the `setInterval` function.

Comment: You never call `crear_div`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object of the class, and use it in the interval function:

```
var the_div = new crear_div();
window.setInterval(function() {
    the_div.desplazar();
}, 250);
```